# Picking a row depending on 2 columns values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Alright so I'm trying to pick a row depending on 2 columns values, here's my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.Seats ss)
{
   var bus = db.Seats.Where(u => u.BusID == ss.BusID && u.SeatID == ss.SeatID).FirstOrDefault();
   bus.SeatState = 1;
   db.SaveChanges();
   return View();
}
```

where db is the EF name, seats is the table name, and ss.BusID holds "1" and ss.SeatID holds "A2"..

heres a picture **after** executing the code :

[image]

my model code :

```
namespace MvcApplication12.Models
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public partial class Seats
   {
      public int BusID { get; set; }
      public string SeatID { get; set; }
      public Nullable<int> SeatState { get; set; }
   }
}
```

*I've tried ".Find()" and ".firstorDefault()" alone but still the same result.

So **my problem** is that I want to change the value where the Bus ID is 1 and Seat ID is A2, but as you can see, it changes the value for every row with BusID =1?

Comment: That definitely shouldn't happen. Even if your query is wrong, the `FirstOrDefault` ensures that at most one item is returned and modified. Are you absolutely sure that your data had `0` in SeatState in the other rows prior to running your code?

Comment: Can you post how your tables and models look?  At first glance, I'd say it's at least possible that the issue is that you're grabbing the whole `Bus` and setting every `SeatState = 1`, when what you want is just the specific seat.

Comment: Yup im pretty sure, i've manually edited it back to zeros and refreshed the DB many times, its all zeros.

Comment: @AllenG ive updated the post with the model code, and yes thats what happening , i just want to change the seatState for one specific seat.

Comment: How's your private key defined in the model? Is it generating something like update seatstate = 1 where busid = 1?

Comment: @WouterSimons its supposed to be update SeatState = 1 where BusId=1 AND SeatID =A2

Comment: Entity framework has a model that determines the PK. I am not sure how you made the model, I usually generate from DB. But sometimes the primary key is not setup properly. Your primary key should be both BusID and SeatID combined. If you look in the model browser you may see that only BusID is currently the PK. You could also try SQL profiler to see what is being executed.

Comment: im not sure, what im supposed to do ? should i re-generate the model from the db ? or should i make it so my table is (SerialNR(PK),BusID,SeatID,SeatState) ?

Comment: An explicit PK in your database will make this problem much simpler and will probably cause it to go away. You can also update the model to have a composite PK. In the diagram view you can right click the BusID and SeatID and make sure Entity Key is selected for both. Or add a Key attribute on your code first model

Answer (score 3):

Please could you try this way:

```
var busList = db.Seats.Where(u => u.BusID == ss.BusID && u.SeatID == ss.SeatID).ToList();

foreach(var bus in busList) 
   bus.SeatState = 1;

db.SaveChanges();
```

My code saves each row in you table that has necessary SeatID and BusID. Please let me know in case of.